# Checkbox is shown twice on select one radio button primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have selectOneRadio component in form with wizard and I have checkbox which should be enabled if first radio button is select. Here is my code for radio button:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="decision" value="#{bean.decisionApproved}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Approved" itemValue="true" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Declined"  itemValue="false"/>
                                    <p:ajax update="permitPriniting"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

Here is my code for checkbox:

```
  <h:panelGroup id="permitPriniting">
     <p:column colspan="2">
             <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.printingApproved}" 
                                                             id="printingApId"
                                                             disabled="#{bean.decisionApproved  ne true}">
```

However when I select first radio button , the checkbox is not enabled and it is shown twice, like it is rendered again.

Comment: Are you sure, the value of `bean.decisionApproved` is correctly transported into `requestForAuthorizationForAmmunitonPurchaseBean.request.decisionApproved`? Also, you might simplify your condition to `requestForAuthorizationForAmmunitonPurchaseBean.request.decisionApproved` as it evaluates to a boolean, I assume.

Comment: yes I am sure. I have updated the question

Comment: Does the getter for `bean.decisionApproved` is getting called after the AJAX event is triggered and does it contain the correct value? Also, please try it with a simplified condition `disabled="#{not bean.decisionApproved}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed this:

```
 <p:ajax update="permitPriniting"/>
```

to this:

```
 <p:ajax update="printingApId"/>
```

And it works:)

Comment: This is very weird... I'm almost 100% sure something else was also going on. Something that is not visible in the code you posted (since you did not post a [mcve]

Comment: @Kukeltje Hmm, `column` in a `panelGroup`, is this ok? Maybe another solution is changing a `panelGroup` to a `panelGrid`.